# Customizing RSS Feed in my Website

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I used the following link to the RSS Feed in my website:
http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-build-a-super-duper-news-scroller/

Actually, this link is very nice. But my problem with customizing the RSS Feed size to fit it properly with my website.
I want to get RSS from http://www.ted.com/
I added the following link as a source for RSS Feed:

```
 $feed = new SimplePie('http://feeds.feedburner.com/TEDTalks_video');
```

I did everything right, but the problem with me now is when I modified the CSS file to the following:

```
 #widget {
overflow: hidden;
background: #e3e3e3;
padding: 1em;
border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
height: 300px; /* You should adjust this height for your project. */
width: 300px;
position: relative;
float: left;
min-width: 210px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
}
```

I could not be able to get the images and titles completely from the RSS source.
I don't way, so please help me.

Comment: So... this is a CSS issue?  If so, things are just not appearing?  It's VERY difficult to debut CSS without it's corresponding HTML.  Also - there's no need at all to post your PHP info if you're getting that data fine - just post the resulting HTML & CSS.

Comment: I would *bet* that the overflow:hidden, and width:300px is hiding your images past the div's visible area... but that's just a guess until we can see the html.

Answer (score 0):

Customize with **Submit RSS** ,  http://www.submit-rss.com/download.html   :)